# Hi all, I am writing a trigger handler that needs to update the owner of a record to a specific user, but I am getting a DMLexception error

Tags: apex, trigger, dmlexception

I am getting the following error. I am not trying to update the Name field, so I am not sure why I am getting this error. Thank you for your help in advance :)!

> EXCEPTION_THROWN [10]|System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0013z00002iocCMAAY; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, Unable to create/update fields: Name. Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set.: [Name]

Here is my trigger handler class:

```apex
public class TH_transferDeactivatedUserRecords {
    @future
    public static void transferDeactivatedUserRecords(List<Id> deactivatedUsersIds) {
        List<Account> accountRecords = [SELECT Id, Name, OwnerId FROM Account WHERE OwnerId = :deactivatedUsersIds LIMIT 1]; //REMOVE LIMIT AFTER TESTING
        List<User> newOwner = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Name = 'Mule Sync' AND Profile.Name = 'Deploy Users' LIMIT 1 ];
        for (Account a : accountRecords) {
            a.OwnerId = newOwner[0].Id;
        }
        update accountRecords;      
    }
}
```

And here is my trigger for more reference:

```apex
trigger trg_transferDeactivatedUserRecords on User (before update, after update) {
    for (User u : Trigger.new) {
        List<Id> deactivatedUsersIds = new List<Id>();
        if (u.isActive == FALSE && u.CompanyName == 'Consumer Sales Community') {
            deactivatedUsersIds.add(u.Id);
        }
        else{
            System.debug('::::ENTERS ELSE STATEMENT');
        }
        TH_transferDeactivatedUserRecords.transferDeactivatedUserRecords(deactivatedUsersIds);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is because in the trigger declaration you have used up `before update` and `after update`, but when we go down in the trigger, we have not specified when it would run for `isBefore` or `isAfter`.
Try the class below

```apex
public class TH_transferDeactivatedUserRecords { 
    public static void transferDeactivatedUserRecords(List<Id> deactivatedUsersIds) { 
        List<Account> newAccList = new List<Account>(); 
        List<Account> accountRecords = [SELECT Id, Name, OwnerId FROM Account WHERE OwnerId = :deactivatedUsersIds LIMIT 1]; //REMOVE LIMIT AFTER TESTING 
        List<User> newOwner = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Name = 'Mule Sync' AND Profile.Name = 'Deploy Users' LIMIT 1 ]; 
        for (Account a : accountRecords) { 
            a.OwnerId = newOwner[0].Id; 
            newAccList.add(a); 
        } 
        update newAccList; 
    }
```

Comment: I went ahead and edited your answer to add (and format) the code that you included in the comment. In the future, please do not post additional information as a comment when that info is for a question or answer that you wrote. Instead, edit your original post to add the information. Firstly, it is hard to read multiple lines of code (even when formatted) in a comment. Secondly, many readers will not see it in the comment.

Comment: Thank you for the information

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by update the line below:

```
 List<Account> accountRecords = [SELECT Id, Name, OwnerId FROM Account WHERE OwnerId = :deactivatedUsersIds LIMIT 1]; //REMOVE LIMIT AFTER TESTING
```

to

```
 List<Account> accountRecords = [SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Account WHERE OwnerId = :deactivatedUsersIds LIMIT 1]; //REMOVE LIMIT AFTER TESTING
```

All I had to do was remove the Name field from the query.